# SyntaxError in @react-navigation/stack

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation

Hi i'm getting this error when i try to start my react native app.  It's started happening unexpectedly and i cant seem to fix it.

env: ios

react-navigation/stack v 5.2.11

error is as follows

```
error: SyntaxError: /Users/bentait/Desktop/memriio/memriio_app/node_modules/@react-navigation/stack/src/index.tsx: Unexpected token (51:12)

  49 |  * Types
  50 |  */
> 51 | export type {
     |             ^
  52 |   StackNavigationOptions,
  53 |   StackNavigationProp,
  54 |   StackHeaderProps,
```

I have tried the following

1. delete node_modules then npm install
2. clearing the cache with npx react-native start --reset-cache
3. delete package-lock.json and then npm install
4. npm install @react-navigation/stack

Should I be using an older / stable version of react-native/navigation/stack ?

help much appreciated as i am stumped.

Comment: Here is many [solution](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/7978) at github thread.